# Schedule a task to run at specific time when the iOS app is in background state

Tags: ios

**Problem:**

I want to run specific code at specific clock time even if the application is background state.

**Approach Tried:**

1. I tried using NSTimer but the NSTimer pauses when the application enters the background state.
2. I am not using the "Background Fetch" approach, as there will be long time before I want the code to execute.

I have seen an **third party iOS alarm application** which starts playing music when alarm goes off. Per my research, there is no way you can schedule a task in iOS (like Android). I want to know the workaround solution to implement such functionality.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need to run code when your app is in the background? Do it the next time the user opens your app

Comment: @LeoDabus I want to play music at the time set by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Only Way -- **SILENT REMOTE NOTIFICATIONS**

This will awake your app in the background and you can catch the notification in `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)` method.

Something like this...

```
if launchOptions != nil,
        let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable : Any] {
        // put your method here..
    }
```

More on silent notification -- [Silent Remote Notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will the application receive this callback if the notifications are disabled?

Comment: Nope... notifications should be enabled. You need user's permission

Comment: Interesting. The third party application I mentioned above, able to play music when alarm is triggered even if the notifications are disabled. Any other thoughts how this app is able to play music in background?

Comment: Can you share the app URL you are referring too?

Comment: Link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarmy-alarm-clock/id1163786766

Comment: I installed the app and it clearly says "Will need you to allow notifications to wake you up in time". App is not allowing to move forward until i give permission for the notifications. Looks like they are indeed using silent notifications to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Try disabling the notifications and put you device on airplane mode. The application is still able to function properly.

Comment: I tried it, the app will function only if it's in foreground. But when you kill the app with airplane mode on and notifications disabled, app will not fire any alarms. Looks like they are using local and push notifications with NSTimer for foreground.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the reply. I agree with your observation that if we **kill** the app, the alarms are not fired. But if you put the app in the background state by pressing the home button, alarms are triggered (even if the device is on airplane mode and notifications are disabled). Per my understanding, **NSTimer** can only run for 3 minutes if the app is in background state. So, there is still a mystery about how this app is able to trigger an alarm.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with silent push notification but still, you can not be sure that the user will receive the push notification. 
Another option is the schedule local notification but there is no way to execute code from local notification if the user does not click it or application is not opened.
There is no way to guarantee that the code will be executed in the exact time. 
Your question sounds like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49368922/background-fetch-at-specific-time)